# connect() function fails wsagetlasterror() 10038

Tags: c++, winsock

Hello i am a beginner socket/c programmer and from this tutorial i have the connect function returns 10038 error. please help. what am i doing wrong?
also whats the difference between winsock and winsock2?
also in connect() function definition there is int PASCAL
what is pascal for?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock.h>


using namespace std;

 int main(){

    WSADATA wsa;
    cout<< "Iinitializing winsock....";
    SOCKET sa;
    struct sockaddr_in server;

        if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsa)!=0)
            cout << "Failed";

    cout << "initialized";


        if ((sa = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) == INVALID_SOCKET))
            cout << "Could not create socket " << WSAGetLastError();

    cout << "Socket created";

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr ("213.165.64.44");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(7);

    //connect
        if (connect(sa, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0){
            cerr << "connect error" << WSAGetLastError();
            return 1;
        }
    cout << "connected";




return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should look at the documentation what 10038 means:

```
WSAENOTSOCK
10038 (0x2736)
An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.
```

So `sa` is not a socket. Printing out `sa` to `cerr` shows that it is zero, so something around the call to the `socket()` function is bad. Looking at the line more closely reveals that there is a parentheses error in the line:

```
if ((sa = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) == INVALID_SOCKET))
```

the == is executed first, and as the return value of the `socket()` function is not invalid socket, zero gets assigned to sa.
The correct expression would be:

```
if ((sa = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
```

For the other parts of the question:

- winsock (winsock.dll) is v1.1 of the API, winsock2 (ws2_32.dll) is the second version that has many improvements. As it is part of Windows since Win98 (and downloadable for Win95), I'd recommend using at least winsock2.
- `PASCAL` is a macro for `__stdcall`˙, Windows API functions generally use this [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#x86).

Comment: +1 for your answer - I would never have bothered to look so closely. -1 for OP question for crap debugging skills - not reading the socket into a local first so that its returned value could be examined. Sorry, OP, but the level of debugging skill shown on this site is apallingly bad, and getting worse...

Comment: so youre telling me i have bad debugging skills when you yourself wouldnt have caught it? And btw i did look up the error code with wsagetlasterror. i just didnt know what was causing it.

Comment: Also what ide would you reccommend? Im currently using code::blocks, should i change ides?

Comment: @KelvinSilva - I would not even bother to look closely at the code. I would have debugged it and fixed it within 15 minutes.  Sorry if I annoyed you a little, but I stick to my original point - debugging seems to be becoming a lost art.  Use the debugger, simplify complex lines, raise some extra locals, split complex problems down the middle.

Comment: @MartinJames He did say he was a beginner at C. Asking for help when you are learning is a good thing - so be nice. I'm sure there was a time you had to ask for help?